# Golang to PHP Script for decryption

Tags: php, go, encryption, phpseclib

I'm trying to decrypt result from wallester encrypted card number.
I've got an information how to decrypt from their support but in golang, and try to translate it using phpseclib but it failed.

```
    var resp model.GetEncryptedCardNumberResponse    
    rsa := crypto.NewRSA([]byte(rsaPrivateKey))
    decryptedCardNumber := rsa.DecryptOAEPFromPEM(resp.EncryptedCardNumber, crypto.LabelCardNumber)     
    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Decrypted card number: %s", decryptedCardNumber))
```

here my php using phpseclib version 2

```
    $rsa = new RSA();
    $rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents(APPPATH .'rsa/private.pem'));
    $decryptedCardNumber = $rsa->decrypt($encryptedCardNumber, RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP, $label = 'CardNumber');
    echo decryptedCardNumber;
```

example data encrypted:

```
-----BEGIN CardNumber MESSAGE-----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-----END CardNumber MESSAGE-----
```

anyone know similar function golang in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution

Here my script to get decrypt the card number

first I clean the result

```
$encrypted=str_replace("-----BEGIN CardNumber MESSAGE-----","",$encrypted);
$encrypted=str_replace("-----END CardNumber MESSAGE-----", "",$encrypted);
$encrypted=str_replace("\n", "",$encrypted);
```

Start to decode (I'm using phpseclib3)

```
$private = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents('/path/to/key.pem'));
$plaintext = $private->withLabel("CardNumber")->decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted));
echo $plaintext;
```

And get the plaintext